# Prow doesnt show latest build status badge

Tags: kubernetes

Could some one share inputs on below query please

I  added build status badge using prow link. The status badge was showing build-passing until last week but now I see build |no results
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver  I  don’t see the tests that got executed in Prow Deck now.  Does it delete data after a period of time. Is there any way to keep last build data so that badge always reflect last build status instead of build | no results

Comment: Please ask in #sig-testing on Slack instead.

Comment: I did ask https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C09QZ4DQB/p1629790780114300 posted again here since there was no reply on slack

Comment: SIG-Testing doesn't monitor StackOverflow for project support questions, you just either have to be patient or ask in the next SIG meeting.

Comment: Alright @coderanger. New to community ..so getting familiar with the process actually.